# How to prevent a hacker from accessing other user's web dir

Tags: server

My website got hacked today :)
The hacker accessed a website hosted by another user on the same server, then he got access to my /home/website-dir/ !
it's my server and I use it to host some websites for me and my friends,
I want to prevent him from gaining access to another user files because he is moving between users.
Thanks

Comment: Before you go any further, take down your website and those of the other users on your server, format the drive, reinstall your hosting platform and reupload your site from backups or even your development platform. There is no telling what changes this guy made to your server and the safest way is to just nuke it and start over.

Comment: Yeah i did a "chmod 0644 -R " on that server, but now i installed kloxo-mr on another server to move the websites to it and I'll follow your advice it was very helpful to me :)

Comment: Personally I'd suggest to investigate what the attacker did in order to gain access (most likely a reverse shell through an upload mechanism). Analyse the logs (if any) and determine if the attacker was able to root the machine. Learn from it. Format it and avoid it the next time.

Comment: @ Jeroen , he got access to a wordpress plugin files, Thanks a lot for the advice I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably too late for the server as it stands now - there are a number of different ways an attacker could conceal ways back into your system, so your safest course of action is to consider that they've got access, have copied any data on the system that they wanted to, and are free to upload anything they want to to any website on the server. Either restore to a recent system backup (not just site files), then work on securing it, or take a copy of the site files, wipe and rebuild server, then upload site files after manually checking each one individually. Might seem a lot of work, but any other option leave you open to getting attacked again.

There are several ways to prevent attackers from being able to access more than one site despite them being hosted on the same server - you could look at virtual containers (where each site effectively runs on a separate server) or implementing strong access control levels (so if a specific user account is breached, they can only write to files within their designated folders) - it very much depends on your requirements though. Bear in mind that in most cases, files must be readable by the web server user in order for them to be served, so if an attacker has control of that user, they'll be able to read anything within the website folders - if that is a problem, you need to look at OS level separation through something like Docker, although the configuration for a containerised setup is more complex than Apache/nginx virtual hosts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll format the whole server later but now I did a "chmod 0644 -R /home" to prevent him from accessing any website, but I asked the question because I'm installing kloxo-mr on a new server.

Comment: This won't help much if he has also database credentials and access to stored data. Better format the server, make a jail / container for each website, import clean backups and change all credentials.